# GULP создание 2 файлов

Tags: gulp

Использую ***GULP, less, minify-css, rename***

Как можно сделать что бы из LESS делалось 2 файла 
один с *minify-css, rename*, 
а второй бросался просто рядом обычным CSS без каких либо сжатий и т.д. ?

```
gulp.task("less", function() {
    return gulp.src(['./app/less//**/*.less', '!./app/less//**/_*.less'])
        .pipe(concat('style.less'))
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions', 'safari 5', 'ie6', 'ie7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Comment: сохраняете обычную версию, минифицируете, переименовываете, сохраняете сжатую версию .... приведите код, иначе сложно дать ответ удовлетворящий вашей сборке.

Comment: Код чего? задачи для LESS ?

Comment: Таки да, или вы даже не пытались сами решить свою задачу?

Comment: Добавил к сообщению. Гуглил конечно но что то результатов это не дало.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему просто добавив еще одну задачу для **LESS** убрав из нее ***minify-css, rename***

Answer (score 0):

В этой же задаче нужно поставить 2й .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
В результате получим задачу вида

```
gulp.task("less", function() {
    return gulp.src(['./app/less//**/*.less', '!./app/less//**/_*.less'])
        .pipe(concat('style.less'))
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions', 'safari 5', 'ie6', 'ie7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```